# require_once produce strange behavior for different file

Tags: php, require-once

My directory looks like this:

```
+script.php
+utils
++class.Picture.php
++class.PacDb.php
```

And then I try this script in `script.php`:

```
<?php
echo "1\n";
require_once "utils/class.Picture.php";
echo "2\n";
?>
```

It works, and print out `1 2`. But the following script doesn't work:

```
<?php
echo "1\n";
require_once "utils/class.PacDb.php";
echo "2\n";
?>
```

It doesn't work, print out only `1`. I do not know why. So sick of PHP right now.

I should note that two class files have identical content:

```
<?php
?>
```

Comment: Do the two files have the same file permissions on them?

Comment: and the content of utils/class.PacDb.php is?

Comment: Check the content in PacDb.php. There may be an error. Also check your semicolon ...

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer they have identical content

Comment: Can you guys check this on your PHP server and see if you can reproduce please?

Comment: turn on display error perhaps `class.PacDb.php` have error

Comment: To expand on what @ashkufaraz said, make sure you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file. If you make changes, don't forget to restart your web server. If you don't feel like editing the `php.ini` file, add this to the top of `script.php` ~ `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. One file has permission 600 while the other is 644.